# Customize OpenIddict client credentials validation

Tags: asp.net-core, hl7-fhir, openiddict, smart-on-fhir

How does one customize the client credentials validation in OpenIddict client credentials flow, e.g. if you had `grant_type` as `client_credentials` and `client_assertion_type` is  `urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer` and wanted to apply some custom validation for a standard such as [FHIR back-end auth](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/uv/bulkdata/authorization/index.html#protocol-details). This standard has a slightly different set of requirements than the base validation built into OpenIddict, e.g. <s>the `iat` claim is not required</s> [EDIT: fixed in 5.1.0], and the JWKS rules are slightly different.

I see that you can supply a different `JsonWebTokenHandler` ...

```cs
options.Configure( o =>
{
    o.JsonWebTokenHandler = new MySpecialTokenHandler();
} );
```

... but this doesn't have any other context about the overall request.